# Computing power spectral density without averaging

Tags: python, matplotlib, signal-processing, spectral-density

I've been using [psd()](http://matplotlib.org/api/mlab_api.html#matplotlib.mlab.psd) to compute power spectral density over a .wav file. I've shown it to my supervisor and he doesn't want it averaged to compute the Pxx:

> The |FFT(i)|^2 of each segment  are averaged to compute Pxx

He suggested I use PSD but overlap it manually a frame at a time instead of passing in the whole array of data. I've attempted it and it looks like this:

```
def spec_draw(imag_array):
    overlap_step = len(imag_array) / 128
    temp = []
    values = []
    for x in range(0, len(imag_array), overlap_step-overlap_step/2):
        try:
            for i in range(0, overlap_step):
                temp.append(imag_array[x+i])
        except:
            pass
        values.append(psd(temp, sides='onesided'))
        temp = []


    print values
```

Where `imag_array` is an array of data from a wave file. I've sent it to him and he doesn't understand Python very well and since he can't run it, he can't debug it. Does this look correct?

Comment: Is this Python 3.x or 2.x? If 2.x, `overlap_step  = len(imag_array) / 128` would be integer division, so is it guaranteed that len(imag_array) is a multiple of 128?

Comment: The naked `try... except: pass` which catches all exceptions is generally considered to be very bad style as it will suppress unexpected exceptions too. Is it there to catch `IndexError, ArithmeticError, MemoryError...?`  Use  a named list of exception-types instead.